# retrieve data from JSON object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dataframe

I'm in trouble with a JSON object in JS. 
I would like to retrieve an array of value for each string, for all objects in a data collection.

for instance, I have

```
mystuff = [{"item1":"12", "item2":"25", "item3":"16"},
{"item1":"14", "item2":"21", "item3":"18"},
{"item1":"13", "item2":"22", "item3":"17"}]
```

and I'm looking for

```
theGoodOne = [{"item1":["12", "14","13"]},
{"item2":["25","21","22"]},
{"item3":["16","18","17"]}]
```

I believe I have to search around dataframes, but I think my major issue is the bad vocabulary I use to perform a fruitful research.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please include your current js code that you have tried so far and got stuck.

Comment: you could use javascript Map Object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). where the key would be the items sting and value would be another array object.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic script that transforms the data structure:

```js
mystuff = 
[{"item1":"12", "item2":"25", "item3":"16"},
{"item1":"14", "item2":"21", "item3":"18"},
{"item1":"13", "item2":"22", "item3":"17"}];

var theGoodOne = mystuff.reduce(function(acc, el){
  Object.keys(el).forEach(function(k){
    if (el.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      acc[k] = acc[k] || [];
      acc[k].push(el[k]);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(theGoodOne);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.values` to achieve it.

```js
let mystuff = [{"item1":"12", "item2":"25", "item3":"16"},
 {"item1":"14", "item2":"21", "item3":"18"},
 {"item1":"13", "item2":"22", "item3":"17"}];

let theGoodOne = Object.values(mystuff.reduce((c, v) => {
  for (var k in v) {
    c[k] = c[k] ? c[k] : {};
    c[k][k] = c[k][k] || [];
    c[k][k].push(v[k]);
  }
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(theGoodOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the basic transformation you need:

```js
const mystuff = [{"item1":"12", "item2":"25", "item3":"16"},{"item1":"14", "item2":"21", "item3":"18"},
{"item1":"13", "item2":"22", "item3":"17"}];

let response = [];

let keys = []
for(const mystuffKeys of mystuff){
  for(const k of Object.keys(mystuffKeys)) {
    if(!keys.includes(k)) {
      keys.push(k);
    }
  }
}

for(const key of keys) {
  const valArr = mystuff.map((item) => item[key])
  let data = {};
  data[key] = valArr;
  response.push(data);
  
}

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to do using es6 notation like this:

```
let Good = {}

mystuff.forEach(stuff=>{
  for (const key in stuff){
    Good[key] = Good[key] ? Good[key] : []
    Good[key]=[ ...Good[key], stuff[key]]
  }
})


console.log(Good)
```

Now the code is compact and more readable